# Relay: When refetch container is called clears different fragment container

Tags: relayjs, relay, relaymodern

I have two containers on the Query level like so:

```
query home_Query {
      ...AppQuery
      ...RefetchQuery
}
```

The refetch() gets called when the component is mounted, and it triggers a refresh on the AppQuery. However, when that rerender happens, parts of the data for the AppQuery is gone:

[image]

How do I prevent refetch() from doing this?